# How to get object_set in serializer from Many to Many?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to allow saving some specific field only if it responds to some statement. Let me explain.

models.py

```
class classe(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=191)
   groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group')
   persons = models.ManyToManyField('Person')

class Group(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=191)
   persons = models.ManyToManyField('Person')

class Person:
   name = models.CharField(max_length=191)
```

serializers.py

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    persons = PersonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    person_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRekatedField(queryset=Person.objects.all(), write_only=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data, **kwargs):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        person_field = validated_data.get('person_id)
        classe = instance.classe_set #This one doesn't work
        person_classe = classe.persons.all() #This one too
        if (person_field in person_classe):
            instance.persons.add(person_field)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

So, the **person_field** can be saved only if the person is in the actual **classe**.

Everything work fine, but the two commented lines don't, so can't access the if statement.

Does someone know how can I figure it out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Group and Classe are ManyToManyfield with each other; therefore a Group can have many Classe and a Classe can have many groups.

Therefore to get the list of classes of a group:

```
classes = list(mygroup.classe_set.all())
```

In your update function, I'm guessing you're trying to add the person to the group if the person is in the classes associated with that group. If yes, here is what you need:

```
# first get all the associated Classe, you need the '.all()'
# keep in mind that .all() gives you a queryset
classes = instance.classe_set.all()
for c in classes:
    students = c.persons.all() # persons of a classe of this group
    if students.filter(id=person_field.id).exists():
        # if this person is in the persons of this classe of this group
        # then we add this person to this group
        instance.persons.add(person_field)
        break # we only need to add it once, right?
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just did that, but now getting a TypeError. "Field id expected a number but got <Person: John>. Via postman, i'm just sending person_id: 1 . I don't know how does it returns the person name instead of what I'm actually sending (a number). Does validated_data.get('person_id) return a queryset ?

Comment: @Gloubiboulga I see, because in your GroupSerialzer class you have person_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRekatedField(queryset=Person.objects.all(), so when this serializer validate the the post data it got a person object using the id. I updated my answer to fit your need.

Comment: @Gloubiboulga validated_data.get('person_id') does not return a queryset, it returns the validation result of that "person_id". And because this field is PrimaryKeyRekatedField, the default validation result of PrimaryKeyRekatedField is `self.get_queryset().get(pk=data)`, which is going to return a Person object. Reference: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L256

Comment: It works. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help !